# Autohotkey make hotstrings trigger unconditionally

Tags: special-characters, autohotkey

Because times to times, I need to translate text into different languages using special characters not present on the keyboard, like `ı`, `ş`, `ñ`, `ğ`.

I created a script with `AutoHotKey`, transforming the combination of `^ + ^ + s` -> into `ş`, in the same way for the others characters.

The script is working fine, but only working if the character preceding the first `^` is a space or the first letter. For example, when typing `ma^^n` <- this will not transform my character, whereas `^^n` <- will transform it.

Here is the script, I specify that I only learned this language when creating the script:

```
:*c:^^S::
SendUnicodeChar(0x015E)
Return

:*c:^^s::
SendUnicodeChar(0x015F)
Return

:*c:^^i::
SendUnicodeChar(0x131)
Return

:*c:^^I::
SendUnicodeChar(0x130)
Return

:*c:^^g::
SendUnicodeChar(0x011F)
Return

:*c:^^G::
SendUnicodeChar(0x011E)
Return

:*c:^^n::
SendUnicodeChar(0x00F1)
Return

:*c:^^N::
SendUnicodeChar(0x00D1)
Return

:*c:^^c::
SendUnicodeChar(0x00E7)
Return

:*c:^^C::
SendUnicodeChar(0x00C7)
Return

; Find the corresponding letter from the unicode
; and send the input back
SendUnicodeChar(charCode)
{
    VarSetCapacity(ki, 28 * 2, 0)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 0, 1)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 6, charCode)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 8, 4)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +28, 1)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +34, charCode)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +36, 4|2)

    DllCall("SendInput", "UInt", 2, "UInt", &ki, "Int", 28)
}

EncodeInteger(ref, val)
{
    DllCall("ntdll\RtlFillMemoryUlong", "Uint", ref, "Uint", 4, "Uint", val)
}
```

Comment: Add a `?` to each hotstring's options, e.g. `:?*c:^^S::SendUnicodeChar(0x015E)`.

Comment: MCL, why not make this the official answer?

Comment: @MCL, you should post that as an answer so I could accept it ! This solved my problem.

Comment: `Send, {U+015E}` can also be used instead of `SendUnicodeChar(0x015E)` - analogous for the others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [AHK docs on hotstring options](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options):

> **?** (question mark): The hotstring will be triggered even when it is
>   inside another word; that is, when the character typed immediately
>   before it is alphanumeric. For example, if :?:al::airline is a
>   hotstring, typing "practical " would produce "practicairline ". Use ?0
>   to turn this option back off.

Consequentially, your hotstrings should look like this:

```
:?*c:^^S::
   SendUnicodeChar(0x015E)
Return
```

You may also want to globally set the options, so that you won't have to apply them to every hotstring individually:

```
#Hotstring ?*c

::^^S::
    SendUnicodeChar(0x015E)
Return

::^^s::
    SendUnicodeChar(0x015F)
Return
```